# Setting connection variables w/ sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have been wracking my brain on how to set a server variable for a sqlalchemy connection. Specifically I need to have the `foreign_key_checks` variable set to 0 for a few specific transactions. I've poured over the docs and Stack Overflow to no avail. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @ilja-everilä, oh my word, it was that simple!?!?!?! I spent about six hours googling using the exact same phrases that's in that post!!! Thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: I had the benefit of having seen that before and remembered what to look for. It's nice to hear that it was helpful.